# Read text defined under __()

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, translation

I am new to WP Plugin development. I have a theme where texts are included inside __() function for translations, like:

```
__('This is text to be translated');
```

I want to create a plugin which would get the value from __() functions and run through my own defined functions. Suppose the text inside __() contains

```
__("This is JavaScript alert <script>alert('Hello');</script>");
```

I want my plugin to do sanity check before printing it in the browser, something like:

```
function my_sanitizer($text) {
  $text = trim(strip_tags($text)); // The $text is value from __() of above
  return $text;
}
```

and the sanitized text should print in the browser.

How shall I be approaching this, any hints, ideas, solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [`gettext`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) filter hook which is applied to the translated text by the internationalization functions (__(), _e(), etc.). eg:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_sanitizer', 20, 3 );
/**
 * my_sanitizer
 * @param  string $translated_text the translation
 * @param  string $text            the origial text from __()
 * @param  string $domain          text domain
 * @return string
 */
function my_sanitizer( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

    $translated_text = trim(strip_tags($translated_text)); 

    return $translated_text;
}
```